# Get netmaske from CIDR

Tags: c#, .net, cidr, netmask

How do I get the netmask of any [CIDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing), e.g. 
`CIDR=10` > `255.255.0.0`
`CIDR=24` > `255.255.255.0`
`CIDR=25` > `255.255.255.128`
`CIDR=31` > `255.255.255.254`

Answer (score 1):

This will create a byte[4] array with the four netmask octet.
You assign your CIDR to the variable `CIDRInt`

```
int CIDRInt = 26;
int index = 0;
byte[] CIDROctet = new byte[4] { 0, 0, 0, 0 };

for (int i = 1; i <= 32; i++)
{
    if (i > CIDRInt) { break; }
    if (index == 8) { index = 0; }

    if (i > 24)
    {
        CIDROctet[3] |= (byte)(1 << (7 - index)); //index from 7 til -1
        index++;
    }
    else if (i > 16)
    {
        CIDROctet[2] |= (byte)(1 << (7 - index));
        index++;
    }
    else if (i > 8)
    {
        CIDROctet[1] |= (byte)(1 << (7 - index)); 
        index++;
    }
    else
    {
        CIDROctet[0] |= (byte)(1 << (7 - index));
        index++;
    }
}

string CIDRStr = CIDROctet[0] + "." + CIDROctet[1] + "." + CIDROctet[2] + "." + CIDROctet[3];
```

UPDATE:
I like the idea of calculating the netmask as above, but
I ended up creating a "low-tech" class with manual static mappings of `CIDR`<>`Netmask` for assumable better performance and two-way-convertion.
The class also return the netmask-class (A, B or C) and the amount of covered IP addresses of each netmask.
The class is available at [github.com](https://github.com/MrM40/CIDR-Netmask-class)